# Excel output with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a report from my codeigniter project in excel, but I am at a complete loss on how to do it. It already works well, just would like the output in excel rather then a page.

Any tips/pointers/explanations?

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll refer you to this [wiki article](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PHPExcel) from the codeIgniter site, or to [this tutorial](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework)

Answer (score 3):

use PHPExcel Library

put the class folder in  your codeigniter application library and call the PHPExcel class

this works fine with codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

If you need something quick and dirty (and potentially working in FF only), I use this JS solution:

```
function exportExcel(html) {
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(
'<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet><style>body {font-family:Arial} .ean {mso-number-format:0000000000000;}</style></head><body><table>'+html.replace(/[♫^]/gi,'')+'</table></body></html>'));
}
```

And then following link in caption tag of the table

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:exportExcel($(this).parents(&quot;.table1&quot;).html());">Excel</a>
```

It will open as HTML Worksheet, which works for me. As you can see in JS funciton code, you can add styles to columns and/or replace some chars you don't need in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to integrate PHPExcel with codeigniter

1. First download the Php Excel from the website https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/.
2. Then extract the copy and put in the application/third_party folder of codeignitor.
3. Then go to the folder application/libraries and create a file and name it Excel.php. And place the below code:

   require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel.php"; //Change path if required.

   class Excel extends PHPExcel { 
       public function __construct() { 
           parent::__construct(); 
       } 
   }

4.Now create a Controller like Export.php and in its action put the code:

```
$this->load->library('Excel');
$query = $this->db->get('users');

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$col = 0;
foreach ($header as $field)
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:Z1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    $col++;
}

// Fetching the table data
$row = 2;
foreach($query as $data)
{
    $col = 0;
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data[$field]); //change if required.
        $col++;
    }

    $row++;
}

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

// Sending headers to force the user to download the file
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.'export_'.$table_name.'.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the following steps for easy to export the data in excel in codeigniter 3**

**Step 1**   Download the Excel library from given link and put **all file and excel folder** in Library folder ( in application/library )

```
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LJyDvsaFDSlWC-DP6CZLYpHLsweQP5My?usp=sharing
```

**Step 2**  Create controller for export the data like above code

```
      <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

       class Exportexel extends CI_Controller {

           function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Payment_model');
           }

           public function index(){}

           public function excel(){

           $data = $this->Payment_model->getpaymentreceived();
           $i=1;               
           $name = "Devang Hire";

           $html = "<html>";
           $html .= "<body>";
           $html .="<table border=1>";
           $html .="<thead>";
           $html .="<tr>";
           $html .="<th>No.</th><th>Employee Name</th>";
    
           $html .= "</tr>";
           $html .="</thead>";
           $html .="<tbody>";
    
           $html .= "<tr>";
    
          $html .= "<td>".$i."</td>";
          $html .= "<td>".$name."</td>";
          $html .= "</tr>";

          $html.="<tfoot><th></th><th></th></tfoot>";

          $html .="</tbody>";
          $html .="</table>";

         $html .= "<body>";
         $html .= "<html>";
    
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=EmployeeDetails.xls');
    echo $html;

}
```

}